# Change z-index of div 2 once div 1 becomes sticky

Tags: javascript

On this page http://www.younity.co.nz/testScrolling.html  I need to change the z-index of the second navigation menu that appears from behind the video container so that it has a higher z-index and blocks out the grey 'Y' graphic once the initial menu has scrolled off the page. Hope that makes sense. So I need to test that the initial nav menu has started to leave the top of browser or it has left.

This is housing menu 1

```
<div class="nav-wrap-height">                            
   <div class="nav-wrap-box">
        menu
   </div>
</div>
```

When it scrolls to the top '.nav-wrap-height' becomes sticky

```
.nav-wrap-height{
   float:left;
   width:100%; 
   position:relative;
   z-index: 100;       
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
}
```

What I want to do is change the z-index of the second menu (.nav-wrap-box#showNow) once .nav-wrap-height has become sticky

```
<div class="cntrl-nav-2" id="showNow">
    <div class="nav-wrap-box">
        menu
   </div>
</div> 

.cntrl-nav-2{z-index:10;}
```

I'm trying the below but not getting any result.

```
<script>
        var distance = $('.nav-wrap-height').offset().top,
        $window = $(window);

        $window.scroll(function() {
            if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
                 $('.cntrl-nav-2').css({
                       z-index:'300'
                    }); 
            }
        });
</script>
```

Any assistance with this problem would be really most helpful.
Cheers
Grant

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong selector

```
$('.nav-wrap-box.showNow')
```

when it should be

```
$('.nav-wrap-box#showNow')
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I had an error in the html layout and have adjusted my html and the script. The second menu's main div 'cntrl-nav-2' is the div I need to target and change the z-index of. Is there something wrong with the script now, it's still not changing the z-index?

Comment: rather than adjusting z-index with jQuery i recommend to add class to navbar element after scroll down for example 'is-sticky' and add z-index property to this class but if you want to add css property with jQuery you shuld try `$('.cntrl-nav-2').css('z-index', 300);`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was after. I was writing the z-index part wrong.

```
var distance = $('.nav-wrap-height').offset().top,
        $window = $(window);         

        $window.scroll(function() {
            if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {

                $('.cntrl-nav-2').css('z-index', 200);                    
            }
            else{                
                    $('.cntrl-nav-2').css('z-index', 10);
                }  
        });
```